# My cat ate a balloon

Tags: cats, health, eating, veterinarian

My cat ate a noodle balloon this morning when me and my dad were making breakfast. When we saw the balloon, we tried to pull it out but she swallowed it moments before my dad was able to take it out of her mouth. My little brother is saying it could’ve been two balloons that were on the floor that she ate. It’s been an hour since and she hasn’t changed her behaviour in any way. She often eats stray things such as leaves from our houseplants and pieces of paper and rubbish off the floor. In fact a month ago she got into some antibacterial wipes and was really lethargic for a day and was fine the next morning. Is this balloon episode anything to be really concerned about?

Comment: a safe environment is part of taking care of your pet.

Comment: Yes thank you serena t it does. I will keep an eye on her feces and behaviour and if anything changes it’s straight to the vets.

Comment: Update- day 2 and she pooed the balloon out by herself, we did give her a bit of milk to get her stomach to open up a bit

Comment: @RashidSchlad Thanks for coming back and writing an update for us, I am happy it turned out to be all right!